# Adding custom field in prices tab in backend

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, price

I want to create a custom field called `Price1`. I tried this code.

```
$fieldset->addField('Price1','text', array(
                'name'=>'Price1',
                'class'=>$attribute->getIsRequired()?'required-entry':'',
                'lable'=>Mage::helper('catalog')->_('Price1'),
                'title'=>Mage::helper('catalog')->_('Price1'),
                ));
```

And I got this error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getIsRequired() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\multiplecurrencies\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Attributes.php on line 71
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `$attribute` variable?

Comment: Umm... I am trying to figure that out.

Comment: The problem originates from there. I think the variable is not defined.

Comment: I changed 'class' value to 'price-box' and got this error. Fatal error: Call to a member function getIsRequired() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\multiplecurrencies\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Attributes.php on line 71

Comment: Where did you add this code? Post the full file.

Comment: I added this code to app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\attributes.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an attribute to the product add/edit page you shouldn't add it by code.
Create the attribute in `Catalog->Attributes->Manage attributes`, then go to `Catalog->Attributes->Manage attribute sets` edit each attribute set and add the attribute by drag and drop in the group called 'Prices'.

Comment: I know that method. I tried programatically for learning purposes. Pity, it didn't work.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni. Nope. it does not work like that.

Comment: Okay, I've one more question. Will post it very soon.